# Hiding columns based upon cell value

Tags: excel, vba, diagnostics

I am not sure why my code is not working. It is intended to recognise when I press a button (saying "Hide1") and search through each column, row by row, looking for cells that have the value `1` Once it does this, it should change the button to say "Show 1". However, when I run it, simply nothing happens.

Here is the macro for Excel:

```
Sub Hide_columns()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

i = 3
j = 4

Do Until i = 26
    Do Until j = 54
        With ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j)
            If .Value = 1 Then
                ActiveSheet.Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame.Characters
                    If .Text = "Show 1" Then
                        .Text = "Hide 1"
                    ElseIf .Text = "Hide 1" Then
                        .Text = "Show 1"
                    Else
                        MsgBox ("VBA has gone wrong.")
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        End With
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: have you debugged your code? Does it reach the line and don't change the text, or doesn't even reach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must re-structure the inner loop:

```
Sub Hide_columns()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

i = 3

Do Until i = 26
    j = 4
    Do Until j = 54
        With ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j)
            If .Value = 1 Then
            MsgBox i & vbCrLf & j
                ActiveSheet.Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame.Characters
                    If .Text = "Show 1" Then
                        .Text = "Hide 1"
                    ElseIf .Text = "Hide 1" Then
                        .Text = "Show 1"
                    Else
                        MsgBox ("VBA has gone wrong.")
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        End With
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Explanation: The first time through the outer loop (for Column A), the row number, `j`, starts at 4 and loops until it's 54. But the second time through the outer loop (for Column B), `j` is still stuck at 54, so no rows in Column B get checked. To fix this, reset `j` to 4 each time you move to a new column, as shown above.